# How to send data from first server to other and get other server response in first server in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express

I want to make a request or api call on server 1, this server then automatically request to Server 2 and send the response back to server 1.  I am using NodeJs and Express.

Example:

```
app.post('/api/Is', function(req, response, callback) {

})
```

I am calling that API in postmain as : http://localhost:3000//api/Is

So it should automatically go on http://localhost:5000//api/Is   and send the response back to http://localhost:3000//api/Is call.
I should only call http://localhost:3000//api/Is and in backend code it will take request body and pass it to http://localhost:5000//api/Is and send the response back to http://localhost:3000//api/Is

Comment: What you want is proxy / passing-on API, correct?

Answer (score 1):

you need to use any library to make API call from server1 to server2. below code I am using fetch library.

To install the fetch library

```
npm install node-fetch --save
```

```js
       
       
        //SERVER1//

const fetch = require('node-fetch');

router.get("/api/Is", async (req, res) => {
  try{
    let {success, data} = await getDataFromServer2(req);
    if(success) return res.send({success: true, data: data})
    res.send({success: false})
  }catch(e){
    res.send({success: false})
  }
});

function getDataFromServer2(req){
  return fetch('http://localhost:5000//api/Is', { 
    method: 'post',
    body:    req,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  }).then(res => res.json())
    .then((response)=>{
      return {
       success: true,
       data: response
      }
    }).catch((error) => {
      throw new Error("unable to fetch the roles ")
    })
  }
```

Comment: I need Program like... where first request willl be on server1 and at backend.. it will pass the request body parameter to second server and send the response back to server one....

Comment: thanks but i need code like..... i m calling api on say server1/api  then it should automatically go on server2/api and return the result to me on server1/api  mean only on call my api on server1.... it basically running on server2 and return result on server1

Answer (score 1):

I think you can consider use the the proxy lib like 'node-http-proxy', the most easy way.

otherwise, you must be transfer the request and response use 'http moudle', like this(no debug, not sure it will work perfectly~):

```
const http = require('http');
app.post('/api/Is', function(req, response, callback) {
const options = {
    host:'localhost',
    port:'5000',
    path:'/api/Is',
    method: 'POST'
    // maybe need pass 'headers'?
};

let proxyBody = '';
const req2 = http.request(options, function(res2) {
    res2.on('data',function(chunk){
        proxyBody += chunk;
    }).on('end', function(){
        // here can feedback the result to client, like:
        // const { headers } = res2;
        // response.send(proxyBody)
    });
});
// .on('error'){}  here handle the error response

req2.end();
});
```

Comment: Good advice on using node-http-proxy. Also note your http native code could be improved, as a response is a readable stream and so you can gain syntactic and performance benefits by piping it to the response writable stream rather than appending the chunks and sending it all at once like you are.

Comment: @Paul yes, you are right. If don't need any process with the response, use stream was the best choice. thks.